# uninitialized constant : Name Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Like:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

and I have another model called Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
end
```

when running

```
obj = Post.find(2)
obj.likes.build(post_id: 3)
```

i am getting this error

> uninitialized constant Post::Like

where am i going wrong?

model file names are [image]

Comment: `has_many` requires you pluralize the model name (so it reads correctly).

Comment: sorry it was my typing mistake in here.

Comment: What's the name of the file implementing `Like` class and where is this file placed?

Comment: `obj.like.build(post_id: 3)` still in singular form?

Comment: Ok, then could you show files names?

Comment: Now everything looks ok. Simply calling `Like` in console works ok?

Comment: `obj = Post.find(2); obj.likes.build(post_id: 3)` doesn't make sense, you're creating a like on `Post`#2 and then overriding it to belong to `Post` #3? Unrelated to the question, it's just somethink to rethink :)

Answer (score 1):

Just 'pluralize' `likes`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Like` class should be implemented in the file named `like.rb` and placed in your `app/models` directory.